# Updating table with Ajax from select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have written this bit of code, and The select boxes work, but I'm having trouble updating the table when a choice is selected, Ultimately i want to use this to update a SQL query when a option is selected

```
<?php
include('PDO_db_config.php');
echo '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function statusChange(value) {
        var gender = value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ajax: 1,
                gender: gender
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').text('gender : ' + response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<?php
echo '<p>Gender <select name="gender" id="gender" onChange="statusChange(this.value)">';
echo '<option>Select a Gender:</option>';
$sql2    = 'SELECT * FROM SLC_gender';
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute([]);
$result2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
foreach ($result2 as $gender) {
    $genderS = $gender['gender'];
    echo "<option value=' $genderS '> $genderS </option>";
}
echo '</select></p>';

echo '<td>';
if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['gender'])) {
    echo $_POST['gender '];
    exit;
}
echo '</td>';
?>
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I got it to work with this

```
    function ajax_fun(gnd) {
        $('#response').text(gnd);
    }

    function getval(sel) {
        var gender = sel.value;
        ajax_fun(gender);
    }

<p>Gender <select name="gender" id="gender" onchange="getval(this)">

<td>
    <div id="response"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: `$('#response').text('gender : ' + response)` is supposed to populate an element in your table or something? Right now I see no element with the id `response`, and also you have no table at all, just a floating `<td>` node.

Comment: Table is confusing here :) At first sight, I thought it's the Mysql Table... well if you mean  html cell <td> here ! Try adding an ID attribute following your code. <td id="response">. This fiddle could help you organize your code and jquery events https://jsfiddle.net/0nygk1br/

Comment: Where is `url` in ajax

Comment: why do you need [] IN $stmt2->execute([]);